# Problems adding a component in Eagle CAD

Tags: eaglecad, cad

I'm trying to draw a circuit diagram using Eagle CAD (v 6.5...), but one of the parts that I want to use isn't coming up in the component library. I know the diagram for the component is available since when I click "open" on the related library and browse to it it's there and I'm able to open and edit the part.

Does anyone have any advice as to why I can't browse to this part from "Add", and how to get the part?

It's an INA101HP (the part that's available is INA101_G, which has a close enough symbol for my purposes), which is in the Burr-Brown library (although if I expand the dropdown to look at the contents of the library the part isn't there....)

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Can you add the folder in the Control Panel - on the eagle control panel screen (window 1), go to Options->Directories, then in the Libraries box add a ```;``` after the current contents and add in the directory of the library. Can you see it now?

Comment: Nope - unfortunately nothing happens. It took a few seconds to update the libraries and froze the program, but it didn't add the part. Thanks for the suggestion though

Comment: Do you have the file permissions set correctly on the folder the library file is in? If you put the library somewhere like the project folder (or in fact anywhere you have read/write access to) then @Angs answer should allow you to use it.

Comment: The symbol I want to use is saved within Burr-Brown.lbr which is in the library folder within program files with all the rest of the libraries I'm currently using. I don't know if there are other symbols that it's not letting me see, but it's letting me see hundreds of other symbols/components

Comment: @Callum.Flint After clicking Library-->Use...-->(Your library), go to Library-->Update All

Comment: @derstrom8 Thanks for the idea, but still no luck

Comment: Is your library path included in the directories list? In the control panel window, go to Options-->"Directories..." and add the path to your library after the existing path, separated by a semicolon ;. Then go to the schematic window-->Library-->Use..., select your library, then do the update as I mentioned before.

Comment: You may not even need to do the "Update All" step, but I put it there just in case

Comment: @Callum.Flint update please?

Comment: @derstrom8 You are slightly ahead of me - I went through the process you described, but with no joy. Turns out somebody seemed to start making the device and never finished so all I had was a symbol, so I went through the process for making the device and it now appears in the library. Thanks for all your suggestions and time

Answer (score 1):

@Angs @Tom Carpenter - So it seems that the device was never made - I had a symbol which had been procured from somewhere, but it wasn't linked to a package and wasn't a device in the library (hence why it never came up). So I've made the part and it now appears in the library. Thanks for all your suggestions and time - they are things I will definitely keep in mind when I'm using this software

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a new component to the list via

```
Library > Use > (browse) xxx.lbr
```

[image]

Then you will be able to see the part on `add`

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work - I don't have the option of browsing to a library. When I look at the list of available libraries I can right click on, and select to use a library, but I can't browse to anything, it's more of a toggle feature

Comment: Can you put a print screen what you get when you press Library > use on the menu?

Comment: Not really... If you mean on the toolbar - Library isn't there, if you mean right clicking on the Library dropdown and then clicking use what changes is the colour of an indicator (it goes green to show that the library is being used)...

Comment: I added a printscreen, if you don't have it. Go to the main eagle window (not .sch nor .brd), then Options > User Interface, then select all "Controls" options

Comment: They're all already selected. That looks like a newer version - in my original post I mentioned I'm using v6.5...?

Comment: I have v6.4 of Eagle.

Comment: Strange - 6.5.0 doesn't have a toolbar like that...

Comment: v6.5 should have the menu as well, the same menu exists on v7 as well. If you get the menu, you will solve the problem. Maybe re-install your eagle, or try it on a different PC to see that it is whether your PC related or v6.5 related problem.

Comment: I've posted a screenshot to the original question to show what I can see

Comment: Place a printscreen from schematic window (top menu ... file, edit, .. Library)?

Comment: Aah - didn't realise you meant the schematic window. I've tried what you suggested - Library -> Use -> select the relevant library, and it doesn't add anything. The components I have access to from that library remain the same

Comment: Woops, meant to add this as a comment here, not to the original post. @Callum.Flint After clicking Library-->Use...-->(Your library), go to Library-->Update All